# iCarousel index number of starting image to display

Tags: ios, icarousel

I am implementing the API, and i am comparatively new when it comes to use API in ios.
I can understand that the sample images are taken in a dictionary and when fetched, it comes arbitrarily,  and when the program is runned, the image at index 1 is displayed as the front image. 
I want to make any desired image as the front image one.
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have read the documentation, it says if you want to set the current index (which in turn sets the image first), you will need to set the `currentItemIndex`.

So, lets say you have 10 images in your iCarousel and want to set the third one as the front image. You might have to have something like:

```
[self.carousel setCurrentItemIndex:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

[self.carousel setCurrentItemIndex:3];

setCurrentItemIndex  is set the starting value of Cover Flow.